# Double factorials Combination

Tags: combinatorics

We know that a factorial is consecutive product from 1 upto n and we can used factorials to extend them into combination of k items from n or permutation of k items from n.so my question is using same method we can factorials to double factorials where  the double factorial or semifactorial of a number n, denoted by n‼,[1] is the product of all the integers from 1 up to n that have the same parity (odd or even) as n.[2] That is,For example, 9‼ = 9 × 7 × 5 × 3 × 1 = 945. The zero double factorial 0‼ = 1 as an empty product,so my question is their some analog for combination and permutations for double factorial ,since factorials permutes single item from a collection whereas a double factorial permutes a pair of two objects for a collection of n things where n is assumed even.

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) uses this notation as well.

Comment: this is a standard notation,do you have some ideas to solve the ploblem ,if yes this would be very helpful for me.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Double factorial doesn't permute “a pair of two objects”. There is [Stirling permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_permutation) but the result is a double factorial of an odd number. If the question is “given that $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is a meaningful number, is there a meaning to $\frac{n!!}{k!!(n-k)!!}$ for even $n$ and $k$?” then the answer is “yes, but why?” since $\frac{n!!}{k!!(n-k)!!} = \frac{(n/2)!}{(k/2)!(n/2-k/2)!}$

Comment: I think what you were trying to say in the last sentence is that if $n=2k,$ then $n!!$ is the number of ways to permute $k$ pairs of objects into a list of $n$ objects where the two objects in each pair need to be adjacent to each other but either object in the pair can come first. That is, $k!$ permutations of the pairs, and for each permutation of pairs there are $2^k$ permutations of the objects within each pair, for a total of $2^k k! = n!!$ permutations.

Comment: It helps people understand the question if you are more careful to write grammatical sentences, and not try to fit too many things into one sentence. Breaking the text up into paragraphs rather than one big wall of text can help too. For the math formulas, see the advice in https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Do the numbers in brackets, [1] and [2], signify something?

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice interpretation of $(2n-1)!!$ as the number of ways to partition $2n$ distinct objects into $n$ pairs, where the order of the pairs does not matter.

A separate interpretation for $(2n-1)!!$ is the number of Stirling permutations of order $n$, which are rearrangements of the list $1,1,2,2,\dots,n,n$ such that for each $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, the numbers between the two copies of $k$ are greater then $k$. These are in turn equivalent to rooted plane trees with vertices numbered $0$ to $n$ with the property that every vertex has a label less than its child. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_permutation. These are also related to the [Eulerian numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number#Eulerian_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Finally, whereas $n!$ counts permutations, $(2n)!!=2^nn!$ counts signed permutations. These are bijections $\pi$ from $[-n,n]\cap \mathbb Z$ to itself which satisfy $\pi(-i)=-\pi(i)$ for $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.

Comment: is there a analog for 3 like stiling permutation deals with 2